# how to embed images (data URI scheme) using .rhml files and knitr?

Tags: r, knitr

When converting `markdown` to `html` the default is (I think) to convert an image file into a string and embed it into the `html` file. When running `knit` on an `rhtml` file this is not the case though. Here a separate `figure` folder is generated, which is of course a sensible default setting.

But if I want my images to be embedded, is there a way to achieve this using `rthml` and `knitr` as well? I can't find any options where to declare this.

Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I figured out myself. Seems to work just the same as with `.Rmd` files, by simply passing the string `"base64_images"`to the options argument in `knit2html`.

```
knit2html("foo.Rhtml", options=c("base64_images"))
```

Comment: That is certainly one way to do it, but a more natural way is illustrated in the R HTML vignette: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/vignettes/knitr-html.Rhtml (`opts_knit$set(upload.fun = image_uri)`)

Comment: I know it has been awhile @Yihui, but `opts_knit$set(upload.fun=image_uri)` does not work on mobile. So, if we email the knitted .HTML to someone, and they open on Android or iOS, they do not get the plots. I doubt this is *really* a knitr issue, but is there something we can change in our code to make it work?